# Como reactivar la validacion de bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Mi consulta es la siguiente, tengo un div maestro, donde tengo un formulario con varios campos dentro. El formulario tiene dentro validaciones de Bootstrap:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    limpiarFormulario(frmGarantias);
    limpiarFormulario(frmAsignarGarantia);

    frmGarantias.bootstrapValidator({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        excluded: [':disabled', ':hidden'],
        fields : {
            selTipoGarantia: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty : {
                        message : 'Debe seleccionar garant&iacute;a.'
                    }
                }
            },

            // Hipoteca
            sel_tip_bie_hip: {
                validators: {
                    callback: {
                        callback: function(value, validator, field) {
                            var val_ind_garantia = $('#hid_ind_garantia').val();
                            var val_cod_tip_garantia = $("#selTipoGarantia").val();                         
                            if (val_cod_tip_garantia == '01' && // Hipoteca
                                    val_ind_garantia != '3') {

                                if (esnulo(value)) {
                                    return { valid: false, message: 'Debe seleccionar Tipo de bien.'}
                                }                               
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            // Generico Descripcion
            txt_dir_des_obs_hip: {
                validators: {
                    callback: {
                        callback: function(value, validator, field) {
                            var val_ind_garantia = $('#hid_ind_garantia').val();
                            var val_cod_tip_garantia = $("#selTipoGarantia").val();                         
                            if (val_cod_tip_garantia == '01' && // Hipoteca
                                    val_ind_garantia != '3') {

                                if (esnulo(value)) {
                                    return { valid: false, message: 'Debe ingresar Descripci&oacute;n.'}
                                }

                            }

                            if (value.length > 400 && val_ind_garantia != '3') {
                                return { valid: false, message: 'El valor ingresado debe tener menos 400 caracteres.'}
                            }

                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });

});
```

Mi lógica inicial es que al cargar mi página JSP guarde el contenido del div maestro en un elemento `hidden`.

```
$('#hid_con_gar_html').val($('#frm-garantia').html());
```

Mi lógica final es después borrar el contenido del div maestro y restaurarlo con el contenido inicial que esta en el `hidden`.

```
$('#frm-garantia').html($('#hid_con_gar_html').val());
```

Mi problema es que cuando requiero utilizar el formulario de nuevo, las validaciones de Bootstrap se pierden. Espero que me puedan ayudar con mi problema.

Saludos.

Comment: Entiendo tu problema, el evento está asociado a un elemento, pero estás eliminando dicho elemento... pero retrocedamos unos pasos... ¡¿Para qué estás copiando el contenido del div maestro?! ¿Cuál es el sentido de hacer tal edición? ¿Cuál es el objetivo que estás intentando lograr? Estoy convencido de que existirán mejores formas de llegar a ese objetivo. ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta explicando esto para que puedan responderte con contenido de mejor calidad?

Comment: Es que no puedo borrar los mensajes de validacion de boostrap, ya dicho formulario lo tengo un modal (popup), se quedan pegados, lo mensajes ...

Comment: entiendo el problema, pero realmente te recomiendo intentar responder las preguntas que hice en el comentario de arriba en tu pregunta... Creo que la respuesta que recibas va a depender de tu explicación a por qué estás intentando hacer eso

Answer (score -2):

No lo guardes como `$('#hid_con_gar_html').val($('#frm-garantia').html());`, intenta guardarlo en una variable string global. Creo que suceden problemas al guardarlo así.

Comment: ¿Por qué? ¿Cuál es la razón para afirmar eso y la fuente que lo justifica?

Comment: Es que no puedo borrar los mensajes de validacion de boostrap, ya dicho formulario lo tengo un modal (popup), se quedan pegados lo mensajes ..